# Reduce cost of NAT Gateway data processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

We are having high cost as "EC2: NAT Gateway - Data Processed", as data transferred daily is around 15TB, I can understand NAT gateway charge on data in or out. I tried to do some google and most of them were answering like use VPC endpoint. But VPC endpoint is useful if we have internal aws services. our scenario is like  "Lots of data coming from third party SFTP server (apparently ALSO in AWS), 7 days a week until it’s all transferred". Please suggest a way to reduce cost. We use EMR cluster to produce data, emr ec2 boxes are in private subnets.

Comment: You're saying that you're pulling a lot of data from an external SFTP server, yes? Is it all as compressed as possible? Are you inadvertently pulling the same data repeatedly (which could be optimized via caching, perhaps in S3)? Do you have any options to get this data from S3 instead (which would be zero network cost if in the same region)? Also note that there is an AWS Transfer for SFTP service that might be relevant.

Comment: Yes, external SFTP server, yes compressed, Not same data, its third party so we need to get from there SFTP location

Comment: I would encourage you to find a way to push this data to S3. Perhaps the data provider could mirror it to S3, or you could run a process outside of AWS that pulls from SFTP and then pushes to S3. Data transfer into S3 is free. Data transferred out of S3 to an EC2 instance (e.g. in EMR) is free when the instance is in the same AWS region as the S3 bucket.

Comment: @jarmod I talked to developer about process its like he do have a sftp url > I navigated it and it showed like ec2-public ip, So I think its on EC2 box > Developer copies data on EMR ec2 box, process it > copy to our S3 bucket,
He can not directly copy from STP to s3 as he needs to do some data analysis on ec2 box.

Comment: I'm proposing that you mirror files from the SFTP server to S3 (do this outside of AWS), then download those mirrored files from S3 to EMR/EC2 in the same region, do your processing, then send your results back to S3.

Comment: @jarmod yes thats one way. Thanks for helping out here, If I use a nat instance or a box with EIP, would it resolve my nat gateway cost issue. I am not a AWS guy, please forgive for  basic concepts.

Comment: No, that doesn't change the pricing picture significantly. Data transfer out to the internet, or in from the internet, via public IP or EIP or NAT (in any flavor) is largely the same pricing. NAT Gateway has additional cost over a single NAT instance because NAT Gateway has redundancy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222259/discussion-between-jaishree-mishra-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0):

Moved to EC2 box without Nat Gateway, Yes there is security risk as it would be open on internet, or you should try directly copy on S3 as Jarmod suggested. Nat Gateway charges are very high if process large files.
AWS charging smartly, As per documentation if EC2 and S3 same region, there should not be any S3 out cost, But that needs S3 endpoints, other wise EC2 box would be treated as public IP or Nat gateway (if you have that). Created S3 endpoint and that reduced internal processing cost.